# Crystal Report with Visual studio 2013 aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am totally confused with behavior of SAP Crystal Report which i am using with Visual Studio 2013. When I run my ASP.NET Web Application, I am getting following folder path ***aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81/crystalreportviewers13/***
instead of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13.
I do not have any such folder found in my IIS 7.5 **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web)**. Can you please help me on this? due to this i am not able to see the report.

Please check the below screenshot for the refernce
[image]

Comment: The Crystal runtime builds a url to that folder based on the version of .Net that's installed, even though they create the folder 4_0_3_319 during istallation, they wrongly build in the path with the .net 4.6+ versions. I fixed it by copying the folder and renaming to the correct 4_6 path. Crystal really needs to acknowledge this bug and fix it.

Comment: I was having the same issue, but it was from a web site that did not even reference Crystal Reports, although Crystal Reports is installed on my dev machine. The solution was to delete the `aspnet_client` folder (which in my case required administrator permission to do).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most robust solution is to create a virtual directory under your application in IIS:

1. Go to IIS, Right click your application
2. Add virtual directory Set the physical path to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13\`.
3. Set the virtual Path to /crystalreportviewers13
4. In your web.config file add the following after the root element:

   ```
   <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
       <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
         <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
         <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
       </sectionGroup>
     </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
   ```
5. Then later on in your web.config file, add:

   ```
   <businessObjects>
     <crystalReports>
       <rptBuildProvider>
         <add embedRptInResource="true" />
       </rptBuildProvider>
       <crystalReportViewer>
         <add key="ResourceUri" value="~/crystalreportviewers13" />
       </crystalReportViewer>
     </crystalReports>
   </businessObjects>
   ```

Comment: I've edited your post to show the code. Tip: when you have code blocks in a list item, they need to be indented an extra 4 spaces, otherwise they are treated as prose. Your code was invisible because it consists of tags, which are stripped out of markup text.

Comment: Thanks, I had real difficulty with the code blocks!

Comment: This looks promising, but the paths in the html for including scripts and css for the following ResourceURI="~/Scripts/crystalreportviewer13" turn into:http://scripts/crystalreportviewers13/

Comment: This worked so effectively and consistently that I added it to my installation as an automatic step. Never occurred again, even after multiple framework upgrades. Try it manually and confirm...

Comment: After doing the copy and rename for the last n windows updates (too many), I hoped there was solution/proper workaround to this bug -- thank you so much for showing this solution, whilst not ideal does solve the problem I've had with so many windows updates I'm no in control of.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after battling an blank report (from the client, no issue  using VS debug on server).  I saw the different version while inspecting the source of the blank report, changed the folder name to 4_6_81 and it worked.

Comment: As a follow-up.  I can only speculate that the version (folder name) is corresponding with MS .NET Framework 4.6 (4.6.00081) which is installed on the IIS 8 server.

Comment: I can able to change the folder name as you mentioned above, but in the production server it doesn't  work. Thanks for your valuable time March

Comment: I think the framework which you mentioned is may one of the reason, Last day i installed Visual studio 2015 and its updated my ASP.NET version 4.6, so it may refer with new folder.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new folder under System.Web into your solution, and name it "4_6_81". Then, copy all resources from the folder "4_0_30319" and paste them into the new folder "4_6_81".

This has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 and my crystal report stopped working.

Here is solution working for me

1. Uninstall framework 4.6
2. If it uninstall all framework of  4.x, 4.5.x then reinstall 4.0, 4.5.x

Hope this will work

Answer (score 1):

It is still an issue. Workaround still seems to have to change the folder version under `aspnet_client>system_web>` like;

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

When report pages are blank or stop working just view the source from browser and check `system.web`'s version from  url `../../aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30369/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js`.

Here's SAP's website.
https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/0002250097