# Crystal Report Is Not Showing data In Crystal Report Viewer Using VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports-2013

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
            doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/UserList.rpt"));
            DataSetSample ds = getdata();
            doc.SetDataSource(ds);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
        }
    }
    public DataSetSample getdata()//.xsd file
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblUser", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSetSample ds = new DataSetSample();
        da.Fill(ds, "DataTable1");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

I'm using crystal report manually. This is my .cs file code. Code showing no error but showing blank webpage on browser. don't able to find error......

Answer (score 0):

Download Latest Version of crystal report which supports VS2013 and then refer [this](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-report-shows-a-blank-page/) link.

Comment: Sir i have latest version which works in wizard crystal Report but not working manually

Comment: @Haroon Place your code within try and catch block and see which error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the correct Crystal Run-times and you can debug reports, but not run them when hosted in IIS, the blank screen suggests you are dealing with this issue: [Crystal Report with Visual studio 2013 aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721443/crystal-report-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-client-system-web-4-6-81/36156791#36156791)

You can confirm this by opening F12 developer tools from your browser. You should notice some errors relating to missing JavaScript files like crv.js and some css from a folder like: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_XXXXXX.

It relates to automatic updates of the .Net Framework and how the Crystal Run-time references its static content. SAP is [aware of this](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/0002250097).

You can copy the folder as a temporary workaround: Copy C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319 to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_6_XXXXX based on the path reported by the 404 errors in your developer tools.