# crystal report viewer in browser

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

i try to open crystal report file in browser but when i try to open this shows nothing where as when i try to open report in vs this successfully display but in browser viewer of crystal report not display

web.config assemblies

```
   <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

Comment: Life Saver, helpful!

Answer (score 1):

In your browser, open F12 developer tools. You should notice some errors relating to missing JavaScript files like crv.js and some css from a folder like: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_XXXXXX.

In Windows 10+ operating systems, mainly due to Crystal creates an aspnet_client folder based on .Net framework 4.0, but dynamically determines the path based on the installed framework version to serve up static content required to serve the reports. Since the framework is now updated automatically, the URL to this location will be incorrect once the framework is updated. SAP is [aware of this problem](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/0002250097).

You can copy the folder as a temporary workaround: Copy C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319 to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_6_XXXXX based on the path reported by the 404 errors in your developer tools.

For a more robust solution, see [Crystal Report with Visual studio 2013 aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721443/crystal-report-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-client-system-web-4-6-81/36156791#36156791)

Comment: what i should do

Comment: Run the report, in the blank screen, press F12. Screenshot the errors in the console.

Comment: oh dear. I'd recommend you strip all the css and javascript you are using, to focus on troubleshooting your Crystal issue. There are too many errors to narrow down the cause of the bobj is undefined. Are you sure your IIS is configured to serve static content? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35778344/474702

Comment: Life Saver, helpful!