# Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2053.0 ? Broke Crystal Reports Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

I have a possible issue/solution we have with PDF\Crystal Viewer (Crystal Reports) Report and Dialog Crystal Reports Viewer Export Format List Not Appearing/Rendering in a Web Page on our ASP.NET Application. I am not a .NET ASP.NET Developer, just manage the application internals and config.

On Friday I carried out our 3 Weekly Microsoft Updates. I am concerned that Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2053.0 is the culprit here, but why did it take till Sunday am for the errors to start, a colleague indicated the report function worked OK after the update and reboot on Friday. Has a Service been disabled or shutdown during the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2053.0 Update?

The server produces the report/letter as a PDF initially OK. Request URL: url.pdf in the event log, I can copy this URL and paste the PDF into browser login and display the report, but on the reports request creation within the application, the Crystal Report and Crystal Reports Viewer Export Format List is not working and just gives me a web page with a back button.

I have included some source code that seems relevant to the issue. The Source Code on the blank page with "back" button below is pointing to a location that doesn't exist. i.e. Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2053.0

We have on the server:

```
wwwroot\app\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727
wwwroot\app\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319

<script src="../../aspnet_client/system_web/4_7_2053/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../aspnet_client/system_web/4_7_2053/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css" />
```

The application is working OK on Microsoft.NET 4.7.2053, but just the CrystalViewer report section is broken.

Comment: I don't know CR, but I'd be surprised if the above code is sufficient to help a reader diagnose the problem.  Is there not more detail you can offer?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a .net issue. It's the way the Crystal runtime resolves the version of .net and the aspnet_client folder where they store the static content required by the web viewer. They tried to be clever with the path name based on the current version of .net even if their aspnet_client folder is fixed.

You can copy the folder as a temporary workaround: Copy C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319 to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_7_2053 based on the path reported by the 404 errors in your developer tools, however it will only happen again since Windows 10+ will automatically update the framework.

See [Crystal Report with Visual studio 2013 aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721443/crystal-report-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-client-system-web-4-6-81/36156791#36156791)
and [crystal report viewer in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514243/crystal-report-viewer-in-browser/44516457#44516457) for more details