# Crystal report displays blank page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I am using `crystalreportviewers13` to display a report using Visual Studio 2010. Report gets displayed when it is loaded but when it is hosted on `IIS`, blank page gets displayed.

I have done necessary changes in config file and saved `crystalreportsviewrs13` folder at required location. But I am still getting this error. I am not able to display the report.

Comment: what's your server version of IIS? What's your server Windows version?

Comment: @reckface it is 7

Answer (score 0):

From the blank page enter F12 developer tools. What errors do you see? Are there missing JavaScript files, or errors like 'bobj' is undefined?

- Ensure you have actually installed the `CrystalReportviewers` 13 runtime on the Windows server hosting the report in IIS. You'll know it's installed if you can locate the `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client` folder
- Ensure you have enabled static content under Windows features, common HTTP 
  features
- Ensure you are not facing the .net 4.5+ folder mismatch problem with the Crystal runtime

see: [Crystal Report Issue with IIS - ( bobj is undefined , Crystal report not displaying )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266049/crystal-report-issue-with-iis-bobj-is-undefined-crystal-report-not-display) and [Crystal Report with Visual studio 2013 aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721443/crystal-report-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-client-system-web-4-6-81) for more details

Comment: @  reckface I am not clear with 2nd topic.Please explain

Comment: when you installed IIS for windows, under "Enable Windows Features" is `Static Content` enabled as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35778344/474702

Comment: what was it? It would help the body of knowledge on such issues.

Comment: Actually I had added a subreportobject for adding header to report and it was causing problem.It was populated from another project.I removed subreport.

Answer (score 0):

may be any of your crystal report's js file not found. just add manually that file to your viewer page. I have manually added crv.js file into viewer page and it works fine.

```
<script src="/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js"></script>
```