# What determines the x numbers from that path aspnet_client/system_web/4_x_xx on IIS Server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports on Visual Studio 2019. The crystalreportviewers indicate to that path : aspnet_client/system_web/4_x_xx . What determines the x numbers?

[image]

I have two cases. In the first case my crystalreportviewers  must be located at aspnet_client/system_web/4_8_4110 at my server. In the second case my crystalreportviewers must be located at aspnet_client/system_web/4_8_4330 at another iis server. Which is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

> The Crystal runtime builds a url to that folder based on the version of .Net that's installed, even though they create the folder 4_0_3_319 during istallation, they wrongly build in the path with the .net 4.6+ versions. I fixed it by copying the folder and renaming to the correct 4_6 path. Crystal really needs to acknowledge this bug and fix it.

You can create a virtual directory under your application in IIS. I think this the best practice.

[Crystal Report with Visual studio 2013 aspnet_client/system_web/4_6_81](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721443/crystal-report-with-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-client-system-web-4-6-81)